# Water intake for people who fast

Tags: nutrition, water

Moslems fast in some countries for more than 19 hours. 
Moslem fasting means no eating or drinking at all from sunrise till sun set. 
Is there any evidence that not drinking water for this long period of the day is *harmful* for the body and the brain?

Comment: Usual effects of dehydration happen. Fasting in Ramadan is between sunrise and sunset, right? That's 12 hours or so without water. It's no good but certainly doesn't lead to permanent damage (maybe mood change and difficulty concentrating).